# SpringBoot embedded tomcat server reads unicode character in query parameter as null

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, unicode

I have a rest end point designed in spring boot. Tomcat is being used as embedded server. It takes a query parameter.

1. When I pass query parameter as param1%uFF07 tomcat internally reads parameter as null
2. When I pass query parameter as param1%FF07 tomcat reads as some character.

tomcat only reads '%' character when followed by two hexadecimal numbers, if u is placed after '%' character tomcat parse parameter as `null` with message

> Character decoding failed. Parameter [name] with value [param1%uFF07]
>   has been ignored. Note that the name and value quoted here may be
>   corrupted due to the failed decoding. Use debug level logging to see
>   the original, non-corrupted values.  Note: further occurrences of
>   Parameter errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

Here is spring boot controller code

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

Comment: In second case which character is it?

Comment: uFF07 represents " single double quote character. Here problem is with u character tomcat hates to see it !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a way using filters. Basics about filters could be found over [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/servlet-filters.html). We can intercept request query string there and use Tomcat UDecoder class to parse the query string and if any exception is thrown we can show response of 400

```java
public class SimpleFilter implements Filter {

    private final UDecoder urlDecoder = new UDecoder();
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        String queryString = httpServletRequest.getQueryString();
        if (queryString != null) {
            ByteChunk byteChunk = new ByteChunk();
            byteChunk.setBytes(queryString.getBytes(), 0, queryString.length());
            try {
                urlDecoder.convert(byteChunk, true);
            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                logger.error("Hazarduos character found in request parameter.");
                httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
                return;
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `%` sign in your url, but `%` is symbol in url, to pass `%` as it is... you will have to pass `%25` then it will work as you expected.

So, if you pass `%25uFF07` then it will show you `%uFF07` as value.

No need to change anything in application.properties or any kind of settings. I have tested this in my project.

Please feel free to ask for any clarification. Hope It Helps.

Comment: This does not work it changes default encoding of tomcat from ISO_8859_1 to UTF-8. Basically I have concern with the way tomcat decodes unicode character it just hates any thing after % character other than two hexadecimal digits

Comment: % character should have invoke 400 response. Here parameter get parsed as null which results in 200 response with all unfiltered data.

Comment: What are you trying to say?? Why do you think `%` character should invoke `400` (which is a bad request) ?? I think you must read https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp about url encoding.

It clearly says, `URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits.` and when you manually pass `%uFF07` it looks for `%XX` and here, `XX` means two hexadecimal string (i.e. 0-9 & A-F) but as we know `u` is not a valid hex character, it ignores the value as dirty value. hence shows `null` in variable.

Comment: yes an invalid character which can not be decoded should get response of 400

Comment: Nope, if the character is not recognized that doesn't mean server would send `400` code.. `400` is for if your request (complete HTTP request) is not understood by the server then server sends `400` saying oops I didn get what you want to do.. but in your case, the value of request param is not recognized.. but your request is well recognized, if you put print in your method, you will see the output printed coz server knows which method to execute but gets param values as `null`.